# Problema ao usar CancelEdit() do BindingSource C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Estou criando um CRUD e estou utilizando o componente BindingSource com o DataSource Tipado com minha classe Pais.

No formulario coloquei um textbox ligado ao meu bindingSource na propriedade Nome do meu objeto Pais. Também foi colocado um 2 botões, o novo, onde insiro um novo Pais para cadastro no BindingSource, e o cancelar que cancela a edição.

A minha dúvida é, como faço para o bindingSource cancelar uma edição que realizo? por exemplo, clico no Botão novo, escrevo algo no textBox que é ligado ao BindingSource e quando clicado em cancelar ele voltar ao estado anterior, ou seja, desafazer o que  acabei escrevendo no meu textoBox.

Porque ao clicar no botão novo estou criando uma nova Instância do meu objeto Pais, ou seja, todos os campos null, e quando digito no textoBox(Nome) um texto e clico em cancelar, o bindingSource colocar esse texto escrito no meu campo Nome, então quando clico em cancelar e é executado o CancelEdit() do BindingSource o estado anterior do meu objeto não deveria voltar ao que era antes?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public partial class Pais : EntityBase
{
    public Pais() : base() { }
    public override string TableName { get { return "PAIS"; } }
    public override int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
    public override DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public override string UsuarioCadastro { get; set; }
    public override DateTime? DataAlteracao { get; set; }
    public override string UsuarioAlteracao { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(App.Erp.Data.Entities.Pais);
    }

    private void btnNovo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.Add(new Pais());
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que deu pra entender é que quando você clica no botão novo, o c# cria uma nova instancia. Tenta destruir a instancia manualmente. Faz assim:

```
private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ~NomeDaClasse
    bindingSource1.CancelEdit();
}
```